# RecurrenceTable doesn't evaluate with constant right-hand side

Tags: difference-equations

One of my functions automatically generates systems for `RecurrenceTable`.  Usually works fine, but today I encountered a problem.  If the right-hand side is a constant, it doesn't evaluate:

```
RecurrenceTable[{n[t + 1] == 2, n[0] == 1}, n, {t, 0, 10}]
(* RecurrenceTable[{n[t + 1] == 2, n[0] == 1}, n, {t, 0, 10}] *)
```

One workaround I discovered:

```
RecurrenceTable[{n[t + 1] == 2 + Unevaluated[0 n[t]], 
  n[0] == 1}, n, {t, 0, 10}]
(* {1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2} *)
```

Are there others?  Should this be considered a bug?

Comment: There must be a recurrence equation. You could use `RecurrenceTable[{n[t + 1] == 2 + a*n[t], n[0] == 1}, 
  n[t], {t, 0, 10}] /. a -> 0`

Comment: @BobHanlon It kind of is a recurrence equation, just a degenerate one!  It's exactly the case that this arose when there was a `a*n[t]` term but `a` happened to equal zero.  I'd like to avoid those intermediate algebraic results and just have it run numerically.  Anyhow, I've uncovered some other unexpected issues with `RecurrenceTable` that will require a rethink on my part to solve...