# What are the limitations of RecurrenceTable?

Tags: recursion, core-language

**Background**

Consider a recurrence relationship defined in terms of the following recursive functions (which works correctly):

```
Clear[tt];
tt[p_][0, j_] := 1
tt[p_][i_, 0] := 0 

tt[p_][i_, j_] := p*tt[p][i - 1, j] + (1 - p)*tt[p][i, j - 1]

tt[0.3][11, 11] (* usage example *)
```

**Question:**

What's the proper way to evaluate this using the build-in `RecurrenceTable` functionality?  Or stated another way---is there some limitation in the functional forms that `RecurrentTable` works with that prevents evaluating these types of functions?

For example, the following implementation:

```
Clear[tt, i, j, p]
p = 0.3;
RecurrenceTable[
 {tt[i, j] == p*tt[i - 1, j] + (1 - p)*tt[i, j - 1],
  tt[0, j] == 0,
  tt[i, 0] == 1},
 tt,
 {i, 11}, {j, 11}]
```

only returns the (unevaluated input-form-style output): `RecurrenceTable[{tt[i, j] == 0.3 tt[-1 + i, j] + 0.7 tt[i, -1 + j], tt[0, j] == 0, tt[i, 0] == 1}, tt, {i, 11}, {j, 11}]` instead of providing the numerical output.

What is puzzling is that the `RecurrenceTable` documentation includes an example for the Stirling numbers of the first kind which has a very similar form (and works just fine):

```
Clear[s1, k] (*example from documentation which works fine*)
RecurrenceTable[
 {s1[n, k] == s1[n - 1, k - 1] - (n - 1) s1[n - 1, k], 
      s1[0, k] == KroneckerDelta[k]},
  s1, 
 {n, 6}, {k, 4}]
```

Unlike past Q&A's, this is [not a case where there is a constant right hand side](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/213954/recurrencetable-doesnt-evaluate-with-constant-right-hand-side).  Previous questions have posed similar types of problems where a `RecurrenceTable` does not evaluate, but the same set of equations restated as a set of recursive functions works fine ([example 1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27193/recurrencetable-with-a-recurrence-function-of-two-variables?rq=1), [example 2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86533/why-does-mathematica-not-evaluate-the-difference-recurrence-using-rsolve-or-r?noredirect=1&lq=1)).  Those past answers have all offered the solution, but I'm interested in *why* `RecurrenceTable` is limited in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an educated guess, in the Stirling number example, the recurrence depending on $n-1$ is key. Mathematica expects that. What you are attempting depends on both $i-1$ and $i$. The documentation does not make this clear. However, it is
still possible to use `RecurrenceTable` within its limitation. Using the usual recurrence technique is this code

```
ClearAll[tt, p, q];
tt[i_ /; i <= 0, _] = 0;
tt[i_, 0] := Boole[i > 0];
tt[i_ /; i > 0, j_ /; j > 0] := tt[i, j] =
   p*tt[i - 1, j] + q*tt[i, j - 1] // Expand;
Table[tt[n - j, j], {n, 0, 4}, {j, 0, 3}] // InputForm
```

which evaluates to

```
{{0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, q, 0, 0}, {1, q + p*q, q^2, 0}, 
 {1, q + p*q + p^2*q, q^2 + 2*p*q^2, q^3}}
```

The equivalent code using `RecurrenceTable` is this

```
ClearAll[tt, p, q];
RecurrenceTable[{tt[n, j] == If[j == 0, 1,
    p*tt[n - 1, j] + q*tt[n - 1, j - 1] // Expand],
    tt[0, j] == 0}, tt, {n, 0, 4}, {j, 0, 3}] // InputForm
```

which evaluates to the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why `RecurrenceTable` does not work. But you can easily do it "by hand". For an example, I only calculate i,j up to 6:

```
ClearAll[tt]
tt[0, j_?NumericQ] = 0;
tt[i_?NumericQ, 0] = 1;
tt[i_?NumericQ, j_?NumericQ] = p*tt[i - 1, j] + (1 - p)*tt[i, j - 1];
Table[tt[i, j], {i, 0, 6}, {j, 0, 6}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: Right.  As noted above, my question is more about the "why it doesn't work aspect".